# Bundler using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

TypeScript API exposed `customTransformer` API a few versions ago.

I want to create a transformer that processes import statements (and maybe requires too) to resolve bundle dependencies, like **webpack**, **browserify** or **parcel** do.

Luckily, TypeScript itself uses customTransformer API for very similar purpose already:

[**transformAMDModule** at src/compiler/transformers/module/module.ts line 120](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/transformers/module/module.ts#L120)

However, that code relies on many internal fields/APIs (and not quite doing what's needed here).

Can this task be done within the public API? Even if a simplified/partial version.

---

**TO CLARIFY:** this is about bundling **external dependencies** of the app (such as `react`, `moment`, `lodash`) **and the app code** together into a large piece of JS. Even though `TypeScript` currently supports `--outFile` argument, that only assembles together the app code, **not** dependencies.

P.S. Asking the same question via [**Twitter/**486timetable](https://twitter.com/486timetable/status/1130888690815950848), and will reflect any useful updates back here for searchability.

Answer (score 0):

No official answer, but here's [my own exploration](https://github.com/mihailik/tpck/blob/d62698d2fb1b798e926819e63bdfc99211a95613/src/build/code/findDependencies.ts) on GitHub:

1. You cannot achieve it JUST with custom transformers. Need to do much work up-front, before emit/transform phase.
2. A first phase is to collect module dependencies. That is what [findDependencies](https://github.com/mihailik/tpck/blob/master/src/build/code/findDependencies.ts) does here: takes `ts.Program` and `ts.TypeChecker` objects and sniffs out patterns out of the AST. Ideally it needs to catch:

   - `import ... from "a-module"` statements
   - `require("a-module")` sync calls
   - `import("a-module")` async calls
   - AMD `define` syntax
   - AMD `require` async calls (behaviour different from global sync `require`)
   - maybe - redirecting opted-in globals like `React` --> `import React from "react"`
   - old-syntax TypeScript `import` statements
3. External dependencies -- bundle (recursively).
4. Finally, kick off emit and handle/alias dependencies:

   - just resolve locally if internal to the code
   - inject external pre-bundled ones

Not totally simple, but actually doable. Hope somebody from #TypeScript team can correct any mistakes?